# Return byte array of openxml document

Tags: c#, .net, openxml

I'm using the following code to generate an openxml document and save it on the server and that works fine, however now i'm trying to generate it to a byte stream to serve out straight away without saving to the server but the document gets corrupted in the process.

**Working Code**

```
 public static void CreateWordDoc(List<objReplace> lstReplace, String TemplateFile, String OutputPath)
        {
            File.Delete(OutputPath);
            File.Copy(TemplateFile, OutputPath);

            using (WordprocessingDocument wordDoc = WordprocessingDocument.Open(OutputPath, true))
            {  
                string docText = null;

                using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(wordDoc.MainDocumentPart.GetStream()))
                    docText = sr.ReadToEnd();

                foreach (var ro in lstReplace)
                {
                    Regex regexText = new Regex(ro.Find);
                    docText = regexText.Replace(docText, ro.Replace);
                }

                using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(wordDoc.MainDocumentPart.GetStream(FileMode.Create)))
                {
                    sw.Write(docText);
                }
            }
        }
```

**Code that produces currupted XML - that I want to get working**

```
 public static byte[] CreateWordDocToStream(List<objReplace> lstReplace, String TemplateFile)
        {
            string docText = null;
            byte[] filebytes = File.ReadAllBytes(TemplateFile);
            using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(filebytes))
            {
                using (WordprocessingDocument wordDoc = WordprocessingDocument.Open(stream, true))
                {
                    using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(wordDoc.MainDocumentPart.GetStream()))
                        docText = sr.ReadToEnd();

                    foreach (var ro in lstReplace)
                    {
                        Regex regexText = new Regex(ro.Find);
                        docText = regexText.Replace(docText, ro.Replace);
                    }
                }
            }

            return Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(docText);
        }
```

Comment: Can you try the following:  1. mem.Seek(0) before doc.open, 2. Use UTF8 Encoding 3. Dump of docText to see where it's going wrong